# How to fix Hbase thrift hbase_thrift.ttypes.TIOError: TIOError(_message="Can't get the location")

Tags: python, hbase, apache-zookeeper, thrift

I use Hbase1.1.2 and thrift2 with Python program:

```
def scaner(self, numRows=2, columns=None, filterString=None):
    columns_list = self.create_columns(columns)
    scaner = TScan(columns=columns_list, filterString=filterString)
    scanner_id = self._client.openScanner(self._table, scaner)

    res = self._client.getScannerRows(scannerId=scanner_id, numRows=numRows)

    while res:
        yield res
        res = self._client.getScannerRows(scannerId=scanner_id, numRows=numRows)
```

when run this function, the read  Latency get very high, and after almost 10mins , it carsh, get error:

> hbase_thrift.ttypes.TIOError: TIOError(_message="Can't get the location")

does any hbase configuer should be changed? before use this version of hbase and thrift, i used hbase0.98 and thrift1, it works fine, but on this version, error happen, even hbase1.1.2 and thrift1 still does not work. anyone can tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you may watch more log in thrift server.From

> "Can't get the location"

It seems to thrift server communicate with zookeeper have some error.